# Why does gcc emit 0x0(%r13) in one instruction but (%r13) in another?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, att

I am debugging a piece of code which has the following instruction.

```
mov    %esi,0x0(%r13)
```

Then at another place, I see an instruction like this:

```
mov    %esi,(%r13)
```

I thought the former one moves the contents of `esi` register to address given by contents of `r13 + 0x0`.  With that logic, the latter should also result in the same effect.

1. Is there any difference between these instructions?
2. Why does gcc write the same thing differently?

**EDIT:** The disassembly has been generated using `objdump -S`.

Comment: The reason for `0x0(%r13)` is a fairly esoteric limitation of the x86-64 instruction set encoding. Look up the `ModRM` and `SIB` bytes if you care.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, and likely GNU assembler will output the same encoding for both. Both move the 32-bit value from ESI to the memory address pointed to by R13.

Comment: I'd be curious. was the code you were looking at generated by a human or by a compiler?

Comment: code is generated by GCC,  not by a human!

Comment: And you found both these instructions the *same* way?  Is this from gcc's `-O3 -S` output, or did you get one or both from a disassembler (like GDB's `layout reg`)?  If you got them from different sources, it's just different choices by different tools for how to show the same instruction with a required `disp8 = 0` byte in the addressing mode, because R13 has the same low 3 bytes as RBP, i.e. the ModRM encoding is the same, only the REX prefix bits distinguish them.   If they're both from `gcc -S`, then can you show source that reproduces this?  Maybe one is from inline asm?

Comment: yes, they are in the same binary, but in different functions.

Comment: Please examine the machine code bytes. I think the first one might be using a 4 byte displacement which is fully printed for whatever reason. In any case, they work the same. The difference may be that one version has been generated as `foo(%r13)` where `foo` later turned out to be zero. Using `objdump -dr` on the object file (not the linked binary) you might be able to see that.

Comment: Sure, I will have a look

Comment: @maths-help-seeker: Oh, you're disassembling a binary, not reading gcc's `-S` asm output directly?  Then include the machine code in your question, as well as what disassembler you're using.  (Or not, because I think we already answered your real question.  There is no difference, and the `0` was required because `(%r13)` isn't encodeable with no displacement: that would be the escape code for a disp32 or RIP-relative with no base register.

Comment: Yes, I am using `objdump -S` to dump the disassembly. Sorry for not making that clear. I have edited the question to reflect it. And yeah I think the question has been answered :)

Comment: Don't use `objdump -S` but prefer instead to compile your `foo.c` with `gcc -O1 -fverbose-asm -S foo.c` and then look into the generated assembler `foo.s`. You don't show any [MCVE] but I guess that your `mov    %esi,0x0(%r13)` has some relocation in the object file, so the `0x0` could be replaced by some constant at link time

Comment: @maths-help-seeker: You still left out the hex machine-code bytes.  Use `objdump -drwC foo.o` and copy the whole line, including the machine code and the symbol relocation info which `-r` decodes.